# How To Populate List View Xamarin Using WCF Service

Tags: c#, android, wcf, listview, xamarin.android

I am sure this is very easy to do but I am stuck.... I look all over to find a way to fill a List View in Xamarin Android. 
This is the code I have:

> ```
> public class MainActivity : Activity
> {
>     WipService.BasicHttpBinding_IWipService client;
>
>     protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
>     {
>         base.OnCreate(bundle);
>
>         // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
>         SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
>
>         // Get our button from the layout resource,
>         // and attach an event to it
>         Button getsomebtn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.GetSomeBtn);
>         ListView applist = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.AppList);
>
>         getsomebtn.Click += Getsomebtn_Click;
>     }
>
>     private void Getsomebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         client = new WipService.BasicHttpBinding_IWipService();
>         client.GetWorkerListCompleted += Client_GetWorkerListCompleted;
>         client.GetWorkerListAsync();
>     }
>
>     public void Client_GetWorkerListCompleted(object sender, WipService.GetWorkerListCompletedEventArgs e)
>     {
>         var x = e.Result;
>     }
> ```

The WCF service is working great!!! I get the list in "x" see image below.

[image: As you can see I can see the details of the worker]

My issue is how to populate my ListView which is called applist???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Xamarin android, you cannot populate listviews as you do it in Xamarin forms. You have to use a ListViewAdaptor.

Here is an example,

```
var items = new string[] { "Vegetables","Fruits","Flower Buds","Legumes","Bulbs","Tubers" };
var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, items);
applist.Adapter = adapter;
```

Xamarin has great tutorials. [Please read](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/).

Comment: You got to help me... I know you want me to read, but this does not makes sense.
`var items = new string[] {e.result}`

Comment: What part of the tutorial does not make sense? What is the type of `e.result`? Is it a string?

Comment: it is a list... see the last image

Comment: Can't see the images. If it is a list, why were you trying to do `var items = new string[] {e.result}`? Do you know it cannot be done?

Comment: I know it can not be done... that is what I am desperately asking... Please teach me...

Comment: That has nothing to do with this question. It is basic C#. A string array can have only a string as an element. if it is a list of strings, just use `var items = e.result.ToArray()`

Comment: `cannot convert from 'WippAppAn.WipService.Worker[]' to 'string[]'`

Comment: We cannot teach C# from start to end here. You really need to fully understand the concepts that you are trying to use before you use them. I would say Xamarin android is NOT the right way to lean C#. Android depends on fair amount of Java in certain areas.